# How do I estimate multiple probabilities of multiple values using a conditional multivariate norm in R?

Tags: r, conditional-probability, density-function, multivariate-normal-distribution, density-estimation

I am using the `condMVNorm` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/condMVNorm/condMVNorm.pdf). I can get the density estimate for 1 value as follows.

```
dcmvnorm(x=25,
         mean=c(0.0365670625664382, 25.0443209966689), 
         sigma=matrix(c(0.9591622, 2.036596, 2.036596, 5.306735), nrow=2, ncol=2), 
         dependent.ind=2, 
         given.ind=1, 
         X.given=0)
```

In this example, I am computing the probability of 25 given the means and covariance matrix. However, I need to do this for more values than 25 (e.g. 25, 26, 24, 22.3, etc.). I tried as follows.

```
dcmvnorm(x=matrix(c(25, 24), nrow=2, ncol=1),
         mean=c(0.0365670625664382, 25.0443209966689), 
         sigma=matrix(c(0.9591622, 2.036596, 2.036596, 5.306735), nrow=2, ncol=2), 
         dependent.ind=matrix(c(2, 2), nrow=2, ncol=1),
         given.ind=matrix(c(1, 1), nrow=2, ncol=1), 
         X.given=matrix(c(0, 0), nrow=2, ncol=1))
```

But I get the following message.

```
Error in solve.default(D): system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.89373e-17
Traceback:

1. dcmvnorm(x = matrix(c(25, 24), nrow = 2, ncol = 1), mean = c(0.0365670625664382, 
 .     25.0443209966689), sigma = matrix(c(0.9591622, 2.036596, 
 .     2.036596, 5.306735), nrow = 2, ncol = 2), dependent.ind = matrix(c(2, 
 .     2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1), given.ind = matrix(c(1, 1), nrow = 2, 
 .     ncol = 1), X.given = matrix(c(0, 0), nrow = 2, ncol = 1))
2. condMVN(X.given = X.given, mean = mean, sigma = sigma, dependent.ind = dependent.ind, 
 .     given.ind = given.ind, check.sigma = check.sigma)
3. solve(D)
4. solve.default(D)
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I know I can just loop through and call this `dcmvnorm` once per iteration, but might not be performant. The documentation seem to suggest I can pass in a vector or matrix (as opposed to a scalar), but there's no clear example on how to do this.

Comment: This seems much more to do with programming that statistics so I am voting to close it as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

It doesn't like that because you're trying to invert the un-invertible matrix

```
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.9591622 0.9591622
[2,] 0.9591622 0.9591622
```

which comes from `sigma[given.ind,given.ind]`.